# Как с помощью Hive сохранять радио кнопки?

Tags: flutter, radio, hive

Собственно вопрос в заголовке. Есть Радио кнопки, и нужно чтобы они сами сохранялись (какая была последняя нажата), и изменение цвета фиксировалось.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

const lightColor = 'light_color';

void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await Hive.openBox(lightColor);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Radio List'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: Hive.box(lightColor).listenable(),
        builder: (context, box, widget) {
          Color colorGroup = box.get('groupColor', defaultValue: Colors.black);
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline, size: 100, color: colorGroup),
                Container(
                  width: 150,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Radio(
                        value: Colors.red,
                        groupValue: colorGroup,
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          box.put('groupColor', val);
                        },
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Red',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 24,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 150,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Radio(
                        value: Colors.blue,
                        groupValue: colorGroup,
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          box.put('groupColor', val);
                        },
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Blue',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 24,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 150,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Radio(
                        value: Colors.green,
                        groupValue: colorGroup,
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          box.put('groupColor', val);
                        },
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Green',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 24,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Какую-то мелочь упускаю. То смена цвета происходит, но не сохраняется. То кружчки эти не выделяются. То ещё что-то.
Со Switch'ми делал, всё довольно просто:

```
SwitchListTile(
     title: Text('Tom'),
     value: box.get('tom', defaultValue: false),
     onChanged: (value) {
           box.put('tom', value);
     },
```

Но РадиоКнопки входят в определённую группу, из-за чего что-то не так прописываю.
В общем, буду благодарен любой помощи.